# Jmeter: Using Assertions on jmeter scripts being used in Blazemeter will it cause slowness/increase in response time?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I need clarification that if I use Assertion in our scripts will it make any slowness?

I was using 10 to 15 assertion on my scripts and the type used are Response and Duration assertion, will there is any impact that could cause slowness/increase in response time and other metrics?

Please help me on this by getting the answers from expertise, as the mail address support team.

Answer (score 3):

According to what BlazeMeter say about assertions they only consume CPU and Memory

> All assertions come with a cost, in terms of **CPU or memory consumption**. However, some assertions carry a greater cost than others. According to the JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips guide, the **Response Assertion and the Duration Assertion** are typically lower-impact choices, whereas Compare Assertion and other XML-based ones like XPath Assertion consume more CPU and memory.

The assertions are done at the machine which is running the tests not on the server where the application is running so there is no need to worry about slower response times from the server. The only thing that assertions are going to bother are your processor and the RAM eventually.

Comment: Fine. Thanks Boyan. Can you help me on this->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049984/blazemeter-how-to-enable-vpn-in-blazemeter-to-access-private-networkqa-enviro

Comment: well not really ... anyway have you checked this [BlazeMeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-3-options-running-performance-tests-behind-your-corporate-firewall) and by the way emailing BlazeMeter team is for sure going to be the best solution to find out how to accomplish this. Please "Accept" the answer if it answered this specific question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already got the answer for your question. Just wanted to share additional info that It is not just only for assertion.

The issue will even happen based on the type of response data extractors you have in your test plan. Check [this link](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/) for a simple comparison and to get an idea.

Each and every element in the test plan affects the execution. You need to be very careful what you are adding in the test plan.

Comment: Thanks Vins. Noted. Vins, do you have any idea for this?-"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049984/blazemeter-how-to-enable-vpn-in-blazemeter-to-access-private-networkqa-enviro"

Answer (score 0):

For the above question I got reply from the Blazemter team and here is the Message;
**"Some assertions are consuming a lot of system resources and using a lot of assertions can cause slowness and out of memory errors.
The duration assertion is not very resource consuming, however the Response assertion can consume a lot of memory as it has to fetch the whole page full of data.
I highly recommend reading this short blog post(https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-you-must-use-jmeter-assertions-your-load-tests-0) about how to use assertion in JMeter and also which assertions you should avoid."**