# Blazemeter: How to enable vpn in blazemeter to access private network(QA- Environments)

Tags: performance, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am in need to do Performance testing using Blazemeter for my site established in QA Environment.

I am doing testing for my site established in QA with the help of VPN connection and now I wonder how to do performance testing-Blazemeter on it and how to connect/establish connectivity on it.

Please help me on this....

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-3-options-running-performance-tests-behind-your-corporate-firewall).

- Did you check with [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/contact-us) first?
- You also need to check with your Network team! You might not want to do your load testing through a VPN connection which is not going to give you accurate results. It is better to expose the staging/PROD clone environment outside the network for the load testing - This is the process we follow.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:
Got update from Blazemeter:**
"First, you'll need to whitelist our IPs, so please refer to our IP ranges list:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420645-What-IPs-are-sending-the-traffic

Then, as long as you have the respective credentials to access the VPN, and run your test locally in Jmeter against the target server successfully, you may run your tests in Blazemeter as desired"

We got to buy dedicated IP from them and need to whitelist it from the Network team. Now the connection would have established and can start doing Performance testing.

Kindly refer the link: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-3-options-running-performance-tests-behind-your-corporate-firewall